# IE does not wrap when a space is followed by punctuation

Tags: internet-explorer, word-wrap

When I have a fixed width table or div with text the words will wrap breaking on a space.

In IE 7 8 and 9 if the space is followed by a `: ; . ,` or `/` it ignores the space and extends the table or overflows the div. In IE 6 or quirks mode it extends both the table and the div.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jHXkF/). This displays correctly in Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

Is there a work around for IE to give the same behavior as the other browsers?

Comment: Check this out http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html#suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would normally suggest `<wbr>` but apparently that doesn't work in some versions of IE. However I got it to work in IE8 by adding this CSS:

```
wbr {
    display: inline-block;
}
```